# NetLogo move turtle in labyrinth

Tags: netlogo

i need a little help with programming in NetLogo. I had to make robot walk in labyrinth. Robot can walk only on a black patches (violet patches represent the obstacles). There's one green patch that represents the target or finish line. Robot can go forward, back, left and right and it must go to the target.

I had to make a procedure 'search' that will make robot walk to the target as i call only once that procedure. Robot must look around and always go in the direction where there is more space. If there is in every direction around him the same number of free patches, robot must randomly pick the direction in which it will go to the target. When it comes to the target, it must stop.

I made three procedures (check-forward,check-left and check-right) to give me information about number of free patches and procedure check-target to check when the agent comes on the target. I made procedure 'search' but it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't..I can't find where is the problem. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?!

This is the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOEhD.jpg

Here is my code:

```
breed [agents agent] 
agents-own[
target      // finish
num_forward //number of free patches forward
num_right   //number of free patches right
num_left    //number of free patches left
chance]     //number of directions where there is the same number of free patches    
              (pick one of them randomly)

to check-target
ask agent 0[ifelse [pcolor = green] of patch-here
[set target true]
[set target false]]
end

to check-forward
ask agent 0 [ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = black or [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = 
green
[ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 2 = black or [pcolor] of patch-ahead 2 = green
[set num_forward 2]
[set num_forward 1]]
[set num_forward 0]]
end

to check-left
ask agent 0 [ifelse [pcolor] of patch-left-and-ahead 90 1 = black or [pcolor] of patch 
left-and-ahead 90 1 = green
[ifelse [pcolor] of patch-left-and-ahead 90 2 = black or [pcolor] of patch-
left-and-ahead 90 2 = green
[set num_left 2]
[set num_left 1]]
[set num_left 0] ]
end

to check-right
ask agent 0 [ifelse [pcolor] of patch-right-and-ahead 90 1 = black or [pcolor] of 
patch-right-and-ahead 90 1 = green
[ifelse [pcolor] of patch-right-and-ahead 90 2 = black or [pcolor] of patch-right-
and-ahead 90 2 = green
[set num_right 2]
[set num_right 1]]
[set num_right 0]]
end

to search 
ask agent 0[
while [target = false][
if((num_forward = 2 and num_right = 2 and num_left = 2) or (num_forward = 1 and 
num_right = 1 and num_left = 1))
[set chance random 3
if chance = 0 [forward] //procedure 'forward' moves by one patch forward
if chance = 1 [right]   //procedure 'right' rotates 90° right and moves forward
if chance = 2 [left]]   //procedure 'left' rotates 90° left and moves forward

if(num_forward > num_left and num_right > num_left and num_forward = 2 and num_right = 
2) or (num_forward > num_left and num_right > num_left and num_forward = 1 and 
num_right = 1)
[set chance random 2
ifelse chance = 0 [forward][right]]

if(num_forward > num_right and num_left > num_right and num_forward = 2 and num_left = 
2) or (num_forward > num_right and num_left > num_right and num_forward = 1 and 
num_left = 1)
[set chance random 2
ifelse chance = 0 [forward][left]]

if(num_right > num_forward and num_left > num_forward and num_right = 2 and num_left = 
2) or (num_right > num_forward and num_left > num_forward and num_right = 1 and 
num_left = 1)
[set chance random 2
ifelse chance = 0 [right][left]]

if(num_forward > num_right and num_forward > num_left)[forward]
if(num_right > num_left and num_right > num_forward)[right]
if(num_left > num_forward and num_left > num_right)[left]
if(num_forward = 0 and num_right = 0 and num_left = 0)[backward]  //procedure 
                                                                  'backward' moves by 
                                                                   one patch back
check-target]]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This can't be your actual code, because NetLogo wouldn't let you name a procedure `forward` or `left` or `right`.

You don't need to write `[pcolor = green] of patch-here`, you can just write `pcolor = green`. A turtle has direct access to the variables of the patch it is standing on.

It isn't obvious to me where the problem just from reading it where the problem in your code is, so I don't know what to say other than offer standard debugging advice:

- You say the code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work. Under what circumstances does it work, and what circumstances doesn't it? If you can find a pattern there, that would give you clues to what's going on.
- What was the last version of this code that worked? Go back to that version and try again, but this time, don't add so new much code all at once. Just add a little new code, and make sure that it's working as expected before adding any more. Recall my  response to your last question: try solving a simpler problem first, get it working, then improve it a little, and so on.
- Try adding some `print` statements to your code so the code will "talk" as it runs and show you what it is doing. This is probably the number one technique that programmers use to help them spot problems in their code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered by Seth at another question that you asked earlier :

[NetLogo turtles in labyrinth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752359/netlogo-turtles-in-labyrinth)

you might need to subscribe to questions you ask to get updates when they are answered :)